# Modals from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to figure out what the best approach for using modals in ViewModels are

At the moment I can see these approaches

1. Event in `App.Xaml.cs` is fired, when the data is entered/selected in the modal
2. A dummy `BindingContext` set from the parent `ViewModel` to set the data
3. `BindingContext` with action to set the data on the other ViewModel.
4. `Code-behind` in the modal page, where I have to set a property for the data

At the moment, I am thinking, that approach 1 or 3 are the best, as they are the most easy to test.

But am I wrong? 
Or are there other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/modal/#Passing_Data_when_Navigating. Two approaches are detailed here:

- Passing data through the constructor of the modal page.
- Passing data through the binding context.

Of course, it all depends on nuanced details of what you are trying to achieve, but if you just need data going to the new VM, the passing data through the constructor is great. If you are filling out a form, then the binding context would work.

I'd also recommend taking a look at Prism for Xamarin Forms. It makes passing parameters pretty simple.
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/docs/Xamarin-Forms/3-Navigation-Service.md#passing-parameters

Comment: I need to retrieve data from the modal e.g. when the modal is a calendar. And it wants to get a huge testability

Comment: @LasseMadsen What's wrong with the answer? You mention calendar. Are you trying to create a modal dialog like this https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker/? Better Pickers library has a Calendar picker https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/BetterPickers

Comment: There are not anything wrong with the answer, but I am trying to figure out, what is the correct way to test a modal